# How to get back to Sathorn pier from Yaowarat?

Tags: thailand, routes, bangkok

There are many articles and information on getting to the Chinatown of Bangkok, Yaowarat. But I haven't found any information on returning from Yaowarat to Sathorn pier. I would like to assume that the Chao Phraya express boat that will ferry travellers from the Sathorn Pier to the Ratchwongse Pier (from where we can walk to Yaowarat) will have a return direction to bring travellers back. But I'm cannot find any information on this.

Does the Chao Phraya express boat have a return direction back to the Thaksin BTS station (Sathorn pier) from the Ratchwongse pier? If not, how else can I return from Yaowarat to Sathorn pier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, the ferries run both ways, and all ferries stop at both Central/Sathorn and N5/Rachawongse.  See [official map](http://www.chaophrayaexpressboat.com/en/services/route-print.asp).

Of course, depending on where you are in Yaowarat and where you're going, it might be faster to walk/tuktuk/taxi to Hualamphong and take the MRT from there.